# Calculating value of a variable from correlated variables

Tags: mean, covariance, variable

I have 4 different variables (3 known and 1 unknown) correlated among each other. Y,Z,W are the known variables and X is the unknown variable. I have calculated the correlation coefficients of variable X with every other variable(Cov(X,Y), Cov(X,Z), Cov(X,W)). Using this information, is it possible to calculate the value of X based on this information? If so, how? If it isn't possible, i was wondering whether it would be possible if i had the whole covariance matrix?
Thanks in advance for your answers,
Kind regards.

Comment: If you've calculated the correlation coefficient of every variable, then don't you know the standard deviation of each variable, hence its variance, and hence its Expected value through the relationship $Var(X) = E(X^2)-E(X)^2$?

Comment: Hmm, i just realised that i got it all wrong. I'm sorry. I would actually like to calculate the value of X based on every other variable, so if i have Y,Z,W and Cov(X,Y), Cov(X,Z), Cov(X,W), can i calculate X and how exactly would i do that?

Comment: @StatsStudent how do you know what $E(X^2)$ is?

Comment: Haha, good question @Glen_b.  I though I saw it mentioned in the question, but I think I'm losing it or that was left in memory from another question I looked at today.  You're right -- you wouldn't know $E(X^2)$, of course.  But at any rate, I think my dumb comment made the OP realize that wasn't the question he/she intended to ask!  Do I get points for that?  ;-)

Comment: From me, certainly :D

Comment: Haha.  Glad I could help, @Magna!  Who knew being mistaken could be so fruitful? ;-)